# Campos dinamicos com jsf e ajax não renderizando mascara

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

Tenho um formulario JSF no qual eu adiciono campos `<input>` dinamicamente com AJAX.

Quando eu clico no `<h:commandButton>` que disparar a rotina de adicionar o `<input>` o campo é adicionado porém a máscara que eu defini para ele não é aplicada. E caso eu já tenha digitado algum valor no campo anterior, o memso desaparece.

Gostaria de saber como renderizar a máscara para cada campo que dinamicamente adicionado sem prejuízo dos dados de outros campos.

XHTML:

```
<h:panelGrid id="grid-phone" columns="1" class="accord-son-3">                                        
    <h:dataTable id="table-phone" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.items}" var="item" width="595">                                              
        <h:column><h:outputLabel value="Telefone" /></h:column>                                            
        <h:column ><h:inputText value="#{item.value}" class="column-cad phone" styleClass="phone"/></h:column>                                            
        <h:column>
            <h:commandLink value="Remover" action="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.remove(item)}" class="jump-link" style="margin-left: 65px;"/>                                            
        </h:column>                                            
    </h:dataTable>                                        

    <h:commandButton type="button" value="Adicionar Telefone" class="btn"  style="font:normal bold 12px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; margin-top: 5px" >                                            
        <f:ajax listener="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.add}" render="table-phone" execute="@form"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Java

```
public void add(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    items.add(new Item());
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();  
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(true);  
    session.setAttribute("formulario", marca);
    session.setAttribute("itens", items);
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){     
        $("#form\\:date").mask("99/99/9999");
        $("input.phone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");     
        $("#form\\:cep").mask("99999-999");                      
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando ocorrem eventos no JSF, este renderiza parte da *view* através de Ajax, substituindo os componentes do código HTML por novos.

Muitas vezes isso é imperceptível, mas cada elemento atualizado é um novo elemento recontruído à partir do estado da *view* no servidor.

Este comportamente causa a perda de qualquer alteração ou evento adicionado via Javascript. É algo muito comum ser difícil a integração entre plugins jQuery e componentes JSF por causa disso tudo.

Algo que você pode fazer para contornar a situação é reaplicar as máscaras após o Ajax.

Se você usasse componentes do PrimeFaces poderia usar o atributo `oncomplete` para executar um Javascript ao final do Ajax.

Com a tablib `f`, no entanto, é preciso um pouco mais de trabalho. Segundo [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495468/jsf-execute-javascript-after-fajax) é possível fazer da seguinte maneira:

```html
<f:ajax render="itemsDataTable" 
    onevent="function(data) { if (data.status === 'success') { aplicarMascara(); } }"/>
```

Não se esqueça de colocar o trecho Javascript que aplica a máscara numa função para poder executar o trecho sempre que necessário.