# Adicionar classe Tamanho a Produto

Tags: java

Preciso fazer algo que quando for cadastrar um produto, faça igual uma pizza tenha tamanhos e cada tamanho seu preço.

Então criei uma classe Tamanho.

```
public class Tamanho implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long idTamanho;
private String tamanho;
private Double valorTamanho;
private Long produto;
```

e fiz a chamada dela dentro de minha classe Produto

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
private List<Tamanho> tamanhos;
```

Agora bateu a dúvida como q eu vou adicionar na tela de cadastro pra quando a pessoa clicar em adicionar um tamanho o sistema gerar um campo para o usuario digitar um novo tamanho e assim gravar.

Atualmente estou fazendo assim:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">                        
                <div class="modal-content" style="color: #000; input{background-color: yellow};">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12">
                            <h3>Cadastro de Produtos</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <p:inputText type="hidden" hidden="hidden" id="id" value="#{produtoBean.prod.idProduto}"/>                                   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <mp:input id="nome" label="Nome" value="#{produtoBean.prod.nomeProduto}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <mp:input id="desc"
                                          label="Descrição" value="#{produtoBean.prod.descricaoProduto}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>                           
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">                                       
                                <mp:input id="valor" type="number" label="Valor" value="#{produtoBean.prod.valorProduto}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00"></f:convertNumber> 
                                </mp:input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <p>Categoria</p>
                                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="selection">
                                    <h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" id="categoria" converter="categoriaConverter" label="Categoria" value="#{produtoBean.prod.categoriaProduto}">
                                        <f:selectItems 
                                            value="#{loginBean.pessoaAtual.categorias}"
                                            var="categoria" itemValue="#{categoria}"
                                            itemLabel="#{categoria.tituloCategoria}"/>
                                    </h:selectOneRadio>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <p>Ingredientes</p>
                                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="selection">
                                    <h:selectManyCheckbox 
                                        id="ingrediente"                                                           
                                        converter="ingredienteConverter"  
                                        label="Ingrediente"   
                                        layout="pageDirection"                                           
                                        value="#{produtoBean.prod.ingredientesProduto}">

                                        <f:selectItems 
                                            value="#{ingredienteBean.listarIngrediente()}"
                                            var="ingrediente" itemValue="#{ingrediente}"
                                            itemLabel="#{ingrediente.nomeIngrediente}"/>

                                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <p>Foto</p>
                                <div class="col s12 l6 m6">
                                    <mp:input hidden="hidden" type="hidden" id="imagemProduto" value="#{produtoBean.prod.imagemProduto}"></mp:input>
                                    <p:fileUpload id="upload" update="imagem, imagemProduto" label="Selecionar..." skinSimple="true" mode="advanced"
                                                  fileUploadListener="#{produtoBean.upload}" auto="true"></p:fileUpload>                                                     
                                </div>
                                <div class="col s12 l6 m6">
                                    <mp:image id="imagem" circle="true" width="150" height="150" value="../imagens/#{produtoBean.prod.imagemProduto}" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">                                        
                                <mp:button update=":form1:listaProduto" value="Salvar" action="#{produtoBean.salvar}"></mp:button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27982/campos-dinamicos-com-jsf-e-ajax-n%C3%A3o-renderizando-mascara

Comment: deu certo..obrigado

Comment: Se funcionou coloque a resposta e a marque como correta, dessa forma vc ajudará outros com a mesma dúvida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criei uma tabela:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">                                         
                                <p:dataTable id="listaTamanhos" emptyMessage="" value="#{tamanhoBean.listaTamanho}" var="tam">
                                        <p:column class="center-align" priority="1" headerText="Tamanho">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{tam.tamanho}"></h:outputText>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column class="center-align" priority="1" headerText="Valor">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{tam.valorTamanho}">
                                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00"></f:convertNumber> 
                                            </h:outputText>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column class="center-align" priority="1" headerText="Ações">
                                            <mp:button value="Remover" update="listaTamanhos" action="#{tamanhoBean.removerTamanho(tam)}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:dataTable>      
                                    <mp:input id="tituloTamanho" label="Tamanho" value="#{tamanhoBean.tamanho.tamanho}"/>
                                    <mp:input id="valorTamanho" type="number" label="Valor" value="#{tamanhoBean.tamanho.valorTamanho}">
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00"></f:convertNumber> 
                                    </mp:input>
                                    <mp:button value="Adicionar" update="listaTamanhos, tituloTamanho, valorTamanho" action="#{tamanhoBean.adicionarTamanho()}"/>

                            </div>
```

Nela eu adicionava os valores do tamanho, depois era só pegar o valor da tabela e setar dentro do produto.